# Is "working" the right word for this case?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

From NYTimes:

"With Their Eyes on the Future, the Red Sox Pick Their Man

“We want to build around him,” Chaim Bloom, Boston's chief baseball officer, said of Rafael
Devers, the star third baseman who is working to finalize a $331 million deal."

If i understood it correctly, Rafael Devers is working to finalize a $331 million deal.
if so what kind of work could he do in this dealing other than just deal?

so wouldn't "dealing" be the right word for this? I mean the Boston's chief is working in fact to get the deal done, Rafael Devers is just kaking the deal, make any sense?

Answer (score 3):

In almost any sort of contract of this sort, there will be negotiations between the team and usually the agent of the player.  As with many negotiations, there may be "back and forth" communications and proposals which some people might call "working to finalize".  Often there is an initial agreement in principle where the "big items" like the $331M are set but there may be many details about the "hows" and "whens" as well as cancellation clauses and so on.

So the idea that Devers, by way of his agent, is "working to finalize" is a commonly used phrase in such matters.  It's not "work" in the sense that someone might work to dig a hole but it does imply that there are details to be finalized before there is a signed contract between the parties.

The word "dealing" does not have the same meaning here in my opinion.